# Number of partitions into parts not greater than 9

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions

I'm looking for a closed-form formula for the number of partitions of integer $n$ into integer parts less than or equal to 9. Thanks.

Comment: PLease give more details. i.e. the context of the question, so that we can see if there's another way than painstakingly calculating this. P.S. I second @N.S.JOHN

Comment: Partitions of integer.

Comment: You mean non-zero partitions. Right?

Comment: [Stars and Bars Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) : This might be what you're looking for. You can easily adjust it for the partitions to be non-zero.

Comment: Yes. I'm interested in the number of ways integer $n$ can be represented as sum of other integers greater than 1, but less than or equal to 9.

Comment: You can easily tailor it using the information @DietrichBurde provided. If you need help, I might post a full answer. (Hint: You need to find a bijection.)

Comment: It's not like I don't know how to approach this. But it's quite arduous process. It's not a homework, I don't need to derive the formula myself, I just need the formula itself. And I just thought someone must have already done  that. So don't sweat it, if you don't have the formula. And thanks.

Comment: Umm... Might ${r-1 \choose r-n}$ work? ($r$ is the number you want to partition and $n$ is the greatest partition. In this case, $9$). This might not be what you need. So, feel free to reject. (You might not want all the cyclic permutations.) :)

Comment: No. This won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can show that the number $p_k(n)$ of partitions of $n$ into exactly $k$ parts is equal to the number of partitions of $n$ in which the largest part has size $k$. So you are looking for a formula for $p_9(k)$. Rubinstein has given an explicit formula for $p_k(n)$ in terms of Bernoulli polynomials, see [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0304356). A. Sills has given  Rademacher-type formulas for the restricted partition function.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try. I was hoping for a closed-form formula as a function of integer $n$ though. I've consulted with "Integer partitions" by Andrews. In there closed-form formulas for $p_3(k)$ and $p_4(k)$ are derived, and $p_5(k)$ is provided and is asked to be proven. I have a feeling his approach can deliver formula for $p_9(k)$ as well, but it promises to be quite arduous, so I thought someone must have already done that. :)

Comment: Yes, Sills has an explicit formula of Rademacher-type, i.e., like the explicit formula for the unrestricted partition function $p(n)$ by Rademacher (see Andrew's book).

Comment: Could you me direct towards Sills results? Where do I find them?

Comment: [Here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11139-009-9184-y#/page-1) is a link, and a free one also [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi06Pnuw6LMAhWrbZoKHU1xB1IQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdigitalcommons.georgiasouthern.edu%2Fcgi%2Fviewcontent.cgi%3Farticle%3D1216%26amp%3Bcontext%3Dmath-sci-facpubs&usg=AFQjCNEkbA0yC9yKMAYkNJ-EJ7oCkwh8BA&sig2=FnvJn_GE-6SWZeCtPzOVIg).

Comment: I actually found this: http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/tokhniot/oPARTITIONS1 Formulas in terms of quasi-polynomials for $p_k(n)$ for $k$s up to 60. Only problem is I don't get how to sum quasi-polynomials. For example, for $k=3$ it is suggested one should add these quasi-polynomials: $[[n^2/12+n/2+47/72], [-1/8, 1/8], [-1/9, -1/9, 2/9]]$. Is it something you would happen to know? Thanks.

Comment: ok, I got it. Thanks once again.

Comment: I see, this is an interesting link! I did not know this was available up to $k=60$.